# Simulating Shadings Losses for Solar Field, like PVsyst

Tags: modeling, rendering, shaders, mathematics, versions

**About Me:**
I'm an electrical engineer by Profession with some programming experience in Python and applied Machine learning. I am involved in modelling, optimization and data analysis of renewable energy systems using Python, third - party software such as PVsyst, SAM etc. I have no experience in Blender or any animation software. If the following problem is solved using Blender, I shall be more than happy to learn.

**Problem:**
I have always wanted to simulate the working of a Solar PV Plant (in it's entirety). The traditional tools do the Job such as [PVsyst](https://www.pvsyst.com/features/). But  the software, to be honest does not operate on micro level.
A major problem is the shading scene. So a shading scene may involve parameters as follows;
[image: Ground Mounted PV Plant using Topography]

[image: PV Plant mounted on Buildings]

This involves the use of Topography and building plans; ray tracing techniques for optical problem solving...etc..
My objective is to calculate the shade falling on the PV Planes at different angles of the sun after mutual shadings.
Simple.
I look forward to use Blender and the expertise of forum to tackle such a problem.